# Repeater which Event to use to find a control inside the repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I use asp.net and c#4.

I have a repeater within inside a `HyperLink` Control.

I need to Find the `HyperLink` Control and change some of its properties with some logic before rendering it on the page.

With my code here posted I get a null value for the control so I'm not able to get it.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for your time on this.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterEditorsChoice" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourceEditorsChoice"
    OnItemCreated="RepeaterEditorsChoice_ItemCreated" OnItemDataBound="RepeaterEditorsChoice_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="uxLink" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

### CODE BEHIND:

```
protected void RepeaterEditorsChoice_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            HyperLink myLink = (HyperLink)((Repeater)sender).FindControl("uxLInk"); // ERROR: it is null
            dynamic o = e.Item.DataItem;
            if (o.TypeContent == "AR")
            {

                myLink.Text = @"'<%# Eval(\""Title\"") %>'";
                myLink.NavigateUrl = @"'<%# GetRouteUrl(""ArticleDetails"", new {ContentId = Eval(""ContentId""), TitleUrl = Eval(""TitleUrl"")}) %>'";
            }
            if (o.TypeContent == "BP")
            {
                myLink.Text = @"'<%# Eval(\""Title\"") %>'";
                myLink.NavigateUrl = @"'<%# GetRouteUrl(""BlogPostDetails"", new {ContentId = Eval(""ContentId""), TitleUrl = Eval(""TitleUrl"")}) %>'";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On item data bound

then just `(YourClass)e.Item.FindControl("its name");`